# How to add an OOTB webpart inside a custom webpart programmatically?

Tags: web-part

I created a custom webpart. I would like to add inside this webpart an OOTB webpart (PageViewerWebPart). How can I add a webpart inside a custom webpart programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/541406/557419).

Code from linked answer. (*Notice the user who posted this code mentions it might not compile as it was taken out of a specific implementation)*

```
public class WebPartWrapper : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart {
    protected override void CreateChildControls() {    
        Panel pnl = new Panel();
        this.Controls.Add(pnl);
        var factory = new WebPartFactory()
        WebPart dynamicPart = factory.CreateWebPart("RSSViewer", this.Guid);
        pnl.Controls.Add(dynamicPart);
    }
}

public class WebPartFactory {
    public WebPart CreateWebpart(string webpartName, Guid parentWebPartGuid)
    {
        var config = ConfigurationFactory.LoadConfiguration(webpartName);

        Assembly webPartAssembly = Assembly.Load(config.Assembly);
        Type webPartType = webPartAssembly.GetType(config.Class);
        object actualWebPart = Activator.CreateInstance(webPartType);

        foreach (var item in config.Properties)
        {
            PropertyInfo webPartProperty = webPartType.GetProperty(item.Name);
            object webPartPropertyValue = Convert.ChangeType(itemValue, Type.GetType(item.Type));
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value))
                webPartProperty.SetValue(actualWebPart, webPartPropertyValue, null);
        }

        RunMethod("set_StorageKeyInternal", actualWebPart, new object[] { parentWebPartGuid });
        return actualWebPart as WebPart;
    }

    private void RunMethod(string methodName, object objectInstance, object[] methodParameters)
    {
        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public |
            BindingFlags.NonPublic;

        Type t = objectInstance.GetType();
        MethodInfo m = GetMethod(t, methodName, flags);
        if (m != null)
        {
            m.Invoke(objectInstance, methodParameters);
        }
    }

    private MethodInfo GetMethod(Type instanceType, string methodName, BindingFlags flags)
    {
        MethodInfo m = instanceType.GetMethod(methodName, flags);
        if (m != null)
        {
            return m;
        }

        if (instanceType.GetType() == typeof(object) || instanceType.BaseType == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return GetMethod(instanceType.BaseType, methodName, flags);
    } 
}
```

Comment: thanks! I used only  protected override void CreateChildControls() {    
        
        this.Controls.Add(new MyCustomWebpart() {Title="MyCustomWebpart"}); }